# How to get sharedPreference value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I saved SharedPreference value and I need to get saved value from every class.

**getUrlPreference method**

```
Future<String> getUrlPreferences() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String url = pref.getString("url");
  return url;
}
```

I need to get url from here.

```
usernameValidation(usernameTextField){
  String urls;
  getUrlPreferences().then((url)=> urls = url);
  print(urls);
}
```

But result is `null`

I Used this way, I can get saved value. How to assign to variable?

```
usernameValidation(usernameTextField){
  getUrlPreferences().then((url)=> print(url));
}
```

Comment: take a look on a example on the package page: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usernameValidation(usernameTextField){
  getUrlPreferences().then((url)=> print(url));
}
```

If you succeeded this way, you can try assign like this:

```
     usernameValidation(usernameTextField){
          getUrlPreferences().then((url) {
    getUrl = url;
    print(getUrl);
    });
        }
```